# QGIS/Create-Grid/Calculate-extent-by-layer: Cannot select layers as number of layers exceeds layer-selection-window size and scrolling is not possible

Tags: layers, select, vector-grid, create

I'm using QGIS 3.16 on Win 10. My project contains say hundreds of raster layers and I'd like to create some vector-grids based on distinct rasterlayers by using the *Create-Grid-tool* with the *calculate-extent-by-layer* method. 
My issue is now: I cannot choose my intended layers

- as the number of layers exceeds layer-selection-window size (though
  the window covers my whole display containing three columns of layer
  names),
- as the window shows only the alphabetically first layers
  (which my intended ones do not belong to), and
- as scrolling is or
  seems to be not possible, respectively.

Is this a bug, or am I doing anything wrong, or does it need any 'trick' to get the window content scrolled, ...? Anybody an idea?

Unfortunately I can only post an image of the the main *create-grid*-window (not of the selection-window itself) as I am not able to generate screenshots from popup windows. Clicking on the red marked button will lead by mouseover on *calculate-by-layer* to the layer-selection-window.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, your offer would be of course an alternative at the moment. I quickly depicted my closer intentions in the following comment. **But** as I still hope to get here an answer on my actual question **I would rather open a new question for your py-approach** if you would take you the time for the pyqgis version. So please let me know after having read my 'wishes' and I will open a new thread. And nevertheless, I would be interested whether your QGIS shows the same behaviour?

Comment: I want to create the grids from 6 raster layers according to their pixel size/location (Sentinel2-derived tiles) calculated by the layer extent.
I want to have the grids according to the basic resolution = 10-meter-pixels, but additionally with 5 and 2.5 meters, and each of these grids as point, rectangle and line subversions (points in the middle of the pixel, lines and rectangles along the pixel borders). So if you would do that let me know, and I will open the new question. As well, if you need any additional information.